# accuracy function when labels are not one-hot encoded in NN tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

i am doing binary classification in NN tensorflow without encoding the labels.. everything is fine except the accuracy function always return 1.0
Output is

Epoch 0 completed out of 10 loss: 5536.991802096367

Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss: 1777.5951525866985

Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss: 1442.1777643710375

Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss: 1315.4084038436413
.
.
.

Epoch 9 completed out of 10 loss: 968.3492169082165

Accuracy: 1.0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
import csv,math,time
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation


import tensorflow as tf
df2=pd.read_csv("Book.csv",encoding="latin-1",index_col=0)
df2['iday'].replace(0,1,inplace=True)
df2['imonth'].replace(0,1,inplace=True)

df2['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df2.iyear, month=df2.imonth, day=df2.iday))

print(df2.tail()); 



df=df2[['Datetime','country','longitude','latitude','suicide','attacktype1','targtype1','nkill','nwound','weaptype1','success']]
df.set_index('Datetime',  inplace=True)
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)  #cleaning data!!!


XX = np.array(df.drop(['success'], 1))   #   
XX = preprocessing.scale(XX)            #dividing dataset into features and label

#df.dropna(inplace=True)                 #dropping those rows which contain nulls
yy = np.array(df['success'])  
yy=yy.reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(XX, yy,random_state=2) #training


n_nodes_hl1 = 100
n_nodes_hl2 = 100
n_nodes_hl3 = 100
n_input=X_train.shape[1]
print(X_train.shape)

print(yy.shape)
n_classes=y_train.shape[1]
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    # OLD VERSION:
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    # NEW:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # OLD:
        #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        # NEW:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            total_batch = int(len(X_train) / batch_size)
            print(total_batch)
            x_batches = np.array_split(X_train, total_batch)
            y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in range(total_batch):
                epoch_x, epoch_y =x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: 
           epoch_y})

                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out 
            of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))


        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:X_test, y:y_test}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: This output is generated by some code ? You should look into that. With the piece of information you have shared how would anybody figure out the cause of issue?. Add the relevant code snippet in your question.

Comment: @Akash Goyal i have uploaded the code. Sorry for inconvienience